# which of my friends are NOT like my page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

I created a personal site on FB 4 years ago. Actually I've 2000 friends.
And I've an FB-fanpage.

I want now that all of my friends will "like" (become fan of) my page so that I can close my personal FB-site.

What I see is "1005 friends like [my page]".

Is there a FBQL-statement, which shows me all of the 995 friends of me, which are NOT like (be fan) of my FB-page?

Is it possible to get a list of this friends?

Answer (score 0):

start point http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page_fan/

remember that you cant achieve that unless they allow it, so it is better to just ask them ..

> You cannot expose this information to anyone but the logged-in user,
>   as it is private and to do so would break our Platform Policies

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/friendlist/